# breaking point in CSS

Tags: css, width, media

What I'm doing wrong?

Which div will appear it doesn't depend on resolution, but order in the css file, instead.

If something is missing I might delete it, because I have to cut code and put some more details :)

Here is Html:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styl.css">
    </head>
    <div class="laptop">Laptop</div>
    <div class="ajpad_poziom">Ajpad poziom</div>
    <div class="ajpad_pion">Ajpad pion</div>
    <div class="cos_poziom">Cos poziom</div>
    <div class="cos_pion">Cos pion</div>
    <div class="tel_poziom">Tel poziom</div>
    <div class="tel_pion">Tel pion</div>
```

Css file:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (orientation:landscape)) {
        .laptop{display:none;}
        .ajpad_poziom{display:none;}
        .ajpad_pion{display:none;}
        .cos_poziom{display:none;}
        .cos_pion{display:none;}
        .tel_poziom{display:block;}
        .tel_pion{display:none;}            
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 741px) and (orientation:landscape) {
        .laptop{display:none;}
        .cos_poziom{display:block;}
        .cos_pion{display:none;}
        .tel_poziom{display:none;}
        .tel_pion{display:none;}            
    }
    
    
    
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        .laptop{display:none;}
        .cos_poziom{display:none;}
        .cos_pion{display:none;}
        .tel_poziom{display:none;}
        .tel_pion{display:none;}
        
    }
    
    /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) 
    portrait
    
    */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
        .laptop{display:block;}
        .cos_poziom{display:none;}
        .cos_pion{display:none;}
        .tel_poziom{display:none;}
        .tel_pion{display:none;}
    }
```